# Fast Food Java Program

Tags: java, netbeans

I have to write a program application that allows an employee to enter the number of burgers, fries, and soft drinks that a customer orders.

After my "final total", I should have another part that says "Enter Amount tendered:" and "Change:" from the customer. I have the code written out, I'm not sure what to write out for the amount tendered and the change?

```
     public class FastFood {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
final double pburgers=2.49;
final double pfries=1.89;
final double psodas=0.99;
final double ptax=0.13;

double burgers;
double fries;
double sodas;
double totaltax;
double total;
double tax;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the amount of burgers: ");
burgers = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the amount of fries: ");
fries = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the amount of soft drinks: ");
sodas = input.nextDouble();

totaltax = (burgers*pburgers)+(fries*pfries)+(sodas*psodas);
tax = totaltax*ptax;
total = totaltax + tax;

System.out.format("Total before tax is: $%-5.2f\n", totaltax);
System.out.format("Tax: $%-5.2f\n", tax);
System.out.format("Your final total is: $%-5.2f\n", total);


 }
 }
```

Comment: do you want us to write code for you?

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FastFood {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
final double pburgers=2.49;
final double pfries=1.89;
final double psodas=0.99;
final double ptax=0.13;

double burgers;
double fries;
double sodas;
double totaltax;
double total;
double tax;
double tender;
double change;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter the amount of burgers: ");
burgers = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the amount of fries: ");
fries = input.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter the amount of soft drinks: ");
sodas = input.nextDouble();

totaltax = (burgers*pburgers)+(fries*pfries)+(sodas*psodas);
tax = totaltax*ptax;
total = totaltax + tax;

System.out.format("Total before tax is: $%-5.2f\n", totaltax);
System.out.format("Tax: $%-5.2f\n", tax);
System.out.format("Your final total is: $%-5.2f\n", total);

System.out.print("Enter amount tendered: " );
tender = input.nextDouble();

change = tender - total;
System.out.format("Change: $%-5.2f\n", change);

 }
 }
```